# Laravel find missing row inside the table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have the following table called `TheSeriesEpisodes` made of composite key (seriesID, episodeNo):

```
seriesID | episodeNo | otherField
---------------------------------
1         1           blabla
1         4           blabla
1         5           blabla
1         6           blabla
2         1           blabla
2         2           blabla
2         3           blabla
2         5           blabla
```

As you can see there are 2 series (series 1 and series 2).
Series 1 has episode 2 and 3 missing, Series 2 has episode 4 missing.

How would I get a list of all missing episodes for a particular TV serial.

I can not think about any method stopped here:

```
TheSeriesEpisodes::
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's find the missed number for serial 1

```
$array = TheSeriesEpisodes::where('seriesID', 1)->pluck('episodeNo')->toArray();
```

Now, we can create a new array, using `range`. So, episode starting number is default 1, ending number we can easily find using `max($array)`

```
$range = range(1, max($array));
```

Using `array_dif` we can get missing elements:

```
$missing = array_diff($range, $array);
```